# VS Code PHP debugger does not work with Docker

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, xdebug, docker-for-windows

I am trying to setup a development environment with Docker for Windows and VS Code to debug PHP code.

I have created a Docker container from this Dockerfile:

```docker
FROM php:8.0.10-apache

RUN pecl install xdebug-3.0.4 && \
    docker-php-ext-enable xdebug && \
    mkdir /var/log/php && \
    chown www-data:www-data /var/log/php && \
    chmod 755 /var/log/php && \
    { \
        echo ''; \
        echo '[xdebug]'; \
        echo 'xdebug.mode=develop,debug'; \
        echo 'xdebug.client_host=host.docker.internal'; \
        echo 'xdebug.start_with_request=yes'; \
        echo 'xdebug.log=/var/log/php/xdebug.log'; \
    } >> ${PHP_INI_DIR}/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini && \
    echo 'error_reporting=E_ALL' >> ${PHP_INI_DIR}/conf.d/error_reporting.ini
```

When I start the debugger on VS Code and open a PHP file with my browser, the page loads forever even when I don't put any breakpoint in the PHP file.

If I put a breakpoint in the file, the page still loads forever and the debugger does not stop on the breakpoint: step over/into/out icons are greyed out on VS code and the variables table is empty:
[image: VS Code screenshot]

If I stop the debugger on VS Code, the page loads successfully.

These are Xdebug's logs:

```
[17] Log opened at 2021-09-16 10:39:03.887841
[17] [Step Debug] INFO: Connecting to configured address/port: host.docker.internal:9003.
[17] [Step Debug] INFO: Connected to debugging client: host.docker.internal:9003 (through xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_port). :-)
[17] [Step Debug] -> <init xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" fileuri="file:///var/www/html/test.php" language="PHP" xdebug:language_version="8.0.10" protocol_version="1.0" appid="17"><engine version="3.0.4"><![CDATA[Xdebug]]></engine><author><![CDATA[Derick Rethans]]></author><url><![CDATA[https://xdebug.org]]></url><copyright><![CDATA[Copyright (c) 2002-2021 by Derick Rethans]]></copyright></init>

[17] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" status="stopping" reason="ok"></response>

[17] Log closed at 2021-09-16 10:41:00.782334

[18] Log opened at 2021-09-16 10:41:10.195656
[18] [Step Debug] INFO: Connecting to configured address/port: host.docker.internal:9003.
[18] [Step Debug] INFO: Connected to debugging client: host.docker.internal:9003 (through xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_port). :-)
[18] [Step Debug] -> <init xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" fileuri="file:///var/www/html/test.php" language="PHP" xdebug:language_version="8.0.10" protocol_version="1.0" appid="18"><engine version="3.0.4"><![CDATA[Xdebug]]></engine><author><![CDATA[Derick Rethans]]></author><url><![CDATA[https://xdebug.org]]></url><copyright><![CDATA[Copyright (c) 2002-2021 by Derick Rethans]]></copyright></init>

[19] Log opened at 2021-09-16 10:42:26.969063
[19] [Step Debug] INFO: Connecting to configured address/port: host.docker.internal:9003.
[19] [Step Debug] INFO: Connected to debugging client: host.docker.internal:9003 (through xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_port). :-)
[19] [Step Debug] -> <init xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" fileuri="file:///var/www/html/test.php" language="PHP" xdebug:language_version="8.0.10" protocol_version="1.0" appid="19"><engine version="3.0.4"><![CDATA[Xdebug]]></engine><author><![CDATA[Derick Rethans]]></author><url><![CDATA[https://xdebug.org]]></url><copyright><![CDATA[Copyright (c) 2002-2021 by Derick Rethans]]></copyright></init>

[19] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" status="stopping" reason="ok"></response>

[19] Log closed at 2021-09-16 10:42:31.116586

[20] Log opened at 2021-09-16 10:42:36.631851
[20] [Step Debug] INFO: Connecting to configured address/port: host.docker.internal:9003.
[20] [Step Debug] ERR: Time-out connecting to debugging client, waited: 200 ms. Tried: host.docker.internal:9003 (through xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_port) :-(
[20] Log closed at 2021-09-16 10:42:36.835780

[21] Log opened at 2021-09-16 10:42:38.915095
[21] [Step Debug] INFO: Connecting to configured address/port: host.docker.internal:9003.
[21] [Step Debug] INFO: Connected to debugging client: host.docker.internal:9003 (through xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_port). :-)
[21] [Step Debug] -> <init xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" fileuri="file:///var/www/html/test.php" language="PHP" xdebug:language_version="8.0.10" protocol_version="1.0" appid="21"><engine version="3.0.4"><![CDATA[Xdebug]]></engine><author><![CDATA[Derick Rethans]]></author><url><![CDATA[https://xdebug.org]]></url><copyright><![CDATA[Copyright (c) 2002-2021 by Derick Rethans]]></copyright></init>

[1049] Log opened at 2021-09-16 10:42:40.727353
[1049] [Step Debug] INFO: Connecting to configured address/port: host.docker.internal:9003.
[1049] [Step Debug] INFO: Connected to debugging client: host.docker.internal:9003 (through xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_port). :-)
[1049] [Step Debug] -> <init xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" fileuri="file:///var/www/html/test.php" language="PHP" xdebug:language_version="8.0.10" protocol_version="1.0" appid="1049"><engine version="3.0.4"><![CDATA[Xdebug]]></engine><author><![CDATA[Derick Rethans]]></author><url><![CDATA[https://xdebug.org]]></url><copyright><![CDATA[Copyright (c) 2002-2021 by Derick Rethans]]></copyright></init>
```

and this is VS Code's `launch.json`:

```json
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Listen for Xdebug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 9003,
            "pathMappings": {
                "/var/www/html/": "${workspaceFolder}"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "Launch currently open script",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "port": 0,
            "runtimeArgs": [
                "-dxdebug.start_with_request=yes"
            ],
            "env": {
                "XDEBUG_MODE": "debug,develop",
                "XDEBUG_CONFIG": "client_port=${port}"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "Launch Built-in web server",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "runtimeArgs": [
                "-dxdebug.mode=debug",
                "-dxdebug.start_with_request=yes",
                "-S",
                "localhost:0"
            ],
            "program": "",
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "port": 9003,
            "serverReadyAction": {
                "pattern": "Development Server \\(http://localhost:([0-9]+)\\) started",
                "uriFormat": "http://localhost:%s",
                "action": "openExternally"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Is that the full log, or just a part of it? It looks like Xdebug successfully connected to VS Code, but it's possible it decided not to do anything? That could hint at not having the right path mappings, perhaps. I don't see any configured in your launch file.

Comment: Have you tried adding path mappings? Like `"pathMappings": {"/path/webroot/in/container":"/local/path/to/webroot"}`

Comment: @Derick That was the full log. I have tried again to connect to the page some times and to stop the debugger (I have updated my question with the new logs).

Comment: @Sam020 Yes, tried, but with no result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finally figured out why the debugger did not work: I launched the debug session inside the container (I connected to it through the [Remote - Containers VS Code extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers)) and not from the Docker host. So, in this case, the correct value for `xdebug.client_host` is `localhost`, since both the Xdebug client and the server are on the same host.

To make it work with `xdebug.client_host=host.docker.internal`, I had set up a Docker volume and I started the debugger directly on Windows, without connecting to the container from inside VS Code. In this case I also had to add a path mapping in the `launch.json` file, which maps the Docker volume's path to the workspace folder.

Comment: I have the same issue. `I started the debugger directly on Windows` Do you mean on `WSL2` or `Windows`?

Comment: @ikhvjs If you have enabled Docker on WSL, both should work, since both should be albe to understand the host `host.docker.internal`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. It turns out I didn't set up wel the `pathMappings` in `launch.json`